# Flyway: use Oracle OCI

Tags: oracle, flyway, oracle-call-interface

Flyway's primary Oracle driver is JDBC Thin, configured as below:

URL `jdbc:oracle:thin:@//host:port/service` or `jdbc:oracle:thin:@tns_entry`. 
JAR's are ojdbc8.jar and orai18n.jar, main class is: oracle.jdbc.OracleDriver.

Is it possible to use Oracle OCI driver instead of JDBC Thin? if yes then how to configure this?

Comment: Why do you want to do that?

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name, I faced this issue: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57291663/flyway-create-view-as-with-common-table-expression-cte and wonder for any workarrounds.

Comment: My guess is, that Flyway _parses_ that SQL script incorrectly and only sends part of it to the server - the OCI driver won't change anything for that.

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name, thanks to Your hint I found the root cause in the Flyway's parser for Oracle. I answered it in the mentioned question.