# Flyway: create view as WITH (common table expression CTE)

Tags: oracle, flyway

How to overcome that error?

```
Java version: 1.8.0_131, vendor: Oracle Corporation, runtime: C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_131\jre    
[DEBUG]    com.oracle:ojdbc8:jar:12.2.0.1.0:provided    
[INFO] Flyway Community Edition 5.2.4 by Boxfuse
[INFO] Database: jdbc:oracle:thin:@bdlg3400.na.pg.com:1525:ioptd101 (Oracle 12.2)
[DEBUG] Driver  : Oracle JDBC driver 12.2.0.1.0


[ERROR] Migration R__SOME_VIEW_VW.sql failed
[ERROR] --------------------------------------
[ERROR] SQL State  : 42000
[ERROR] Error Code : 933
[ERROR] Message    : ORA-00933: (non-english description)
[ERROR] Location   : sql\Views\R__SOME_VIEW_VW.sql (...\sql\Views\R__SOME_VIEW_VW.sql)
[ERROR] Line       : 7
[ERROR] Statement  : CREATE OR REPLACE VIEW some_view_vw as
[ERROR] WITH
[ERROR] abc AS
[ERROR] (
[ERROR]     SELECT
[ERROR]         iglp.p_skid,
[ERROR]         LISTAGG(g.g_code, ',') WITHIN GROUP (ORDER BY g.g_code) AS lokd_gate_lst
[ERROR]     FROM ig_l_prod iglp
[ERROR]     JOIN ig_prc ig ON ig.ig_skid = iglp.ig_skid
[ERROR]     JOIN g g ON g.g_skid = ig.g_skid
[ERROR]     WHERE iglp.lock_ind = 'Y'
[ERROR]     GROUP BY
[ERROR]         iglp.p_skid
[ERROR] )
[ERROR] SELECT
[ERROR]     pr.p_skid AS scr_prod_skid,
[ERROR]     lg.lokd_gate_lst,
[ERROR]     pr.*
[ERROR] FROM p pr
[ERROR] LEFT JOIN lokd_gate lg ON lg.p_skid = pr.p_skid
[ERROR] where exists(select 1 from PP_PRC pipo WHERE pipo.PI_P_SKID = pr.P_SKID);
[ERROR]
[ERROR] -> [Help 1]
```

When I move the WITH clause as a sub-query to FROM clause, script is successful. But refactoring this way may cause other views inefficient.

Comment: Using a CTE in a view is valid. Are you sure there isn't something else wrong/missing in your overall statement? Does it work if you run the same script through SQL\*Plus or some other client? It's hard to diagnose from just those 4 lines in the error message. Posting the full view might not be desirable, but can you create a [mre] demonstrating the issue? (Also not sure why you think it would less efficient as a subquery.)

Comment: @AlexPoole we have many views in the project, many of them using several CTEs.

Comment: My guess is, that Flyway _parses_ that SQL script incorrectly and only sends part of it to the server. Can you tell Flyway to take the SQL script "as is"? I don't know Flyway, but e.g. Liquibase has a "splitStatements" attribute for this kind of things to prevent any problems with SQL syntax that the tool does not expect

Comment: I'd be suspicious of the semicolon that's showing at the end of the statement in the log. That is a statement separator (and interpreted by the client), not part of the statement. It will cause this sort of error in JDBC and dynamic SQL calls etc. Does removing that semicolon fix the problem? (Flyway may be fine with it as part of script processing, of course; not something I use either...)

Comment: @AlexPoole, do You have an example of script (create view) where You use CTE?

Comment: You said you already had some? But anyway, [here is a simple demo](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_11.2&fiddle=e6e4c517686adffed6abf4971bbbcd4b). Did you try removing the semicolon from your statement?

Comment: @AlexPoole, I thought You speak about a script run by Flyway, not a general example. Semicolon is not a problem. Other scripts do have semicolons.

Comment: raised an issue here: https://github.com/flyway/flyway/issues/2453

Comment: fixed in v.6.0.0. Originally raised in https://github.com/flyway/flyway/issues/2252

Comment: Seems I was right to be suspicious of the semicolon, just for the wrong reasons, from the comments on that issue log *8-)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The root cause lies in the Flyway's Oracle parser:

```
OracleParser.java

private static final Pattern PLSQL_VIEW_REGEX = Pattern.compile(
        "^CREATE(\\sOR\\sREPLACE)?(\\s(NON)?EDITIONABLE)?\\sVIEW\\s.*\\sAS\\sWITH\\s(PROCEDURE|FUNCTION)");
private static final StatementType PLSQL_VIEW_STATEMENT = new StatementType();
```

Comment: it has been fixed in v.6.0.0. Originally raised in https://github.com/flyway/flyway/issues/2252

Answer (score 0):

The error message is `ORA-00933 sql command not properly ended`, and this may mean that you have some prohibited or conflicting clauses in your query, but in my experience this typically means a comma is missing somewhere or there is a typo.

First some dummy tables:

```
create table ig_l_prod(
  p_skid number,
  ig_skid number,
  lock_ind varchar2(1)
);
create table ig_prc(
  ig_skid number,
  g_skid number
);
create table g(
  g_skid number,
  g_code varchar2(1)
);
create table p(
  p_skid number,
  name varchar2(10)
);
create table PP_PRC(
PI_P_SKID number
);
```

This is the query from your log, with one modification:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE VIEW some_view_vw as
WITH
lokd_gate AS -- *** Replaced "abc" with "lokd_gate" ***
(
    SELECT
        iglp.p_skid,
        LISTAGG(g.g_code, ',') WITHIN GROUP (ORDER BY g.g_code) AS lokd_gate_lst
    FROM ig_l_prod iglp
    JOIN ig_prc ig ON ig.ig_skid = iglp.ig_skid
    JOIN g g ON g.g_skid = ig.g_skid
    WHERE iglp.lock_ind = 'Y'
    GROUP BY
        iglp.p_skid
)
SELECT
    pr.p_skid AS scr_prod_skid,
    lg.lokd_gate_lst,
    pr.*
FROM p pr
LEFT JOIN lokd_gate lg ON lg.p_skid = pr.p_skid
where exists(select 1 from PP_PRC pipo WHERE pipo.PI_P_SKID = pr.P_SKID);
```

The CTE was aliased as `abc`, while the join is to `lokd_gate`--this might just be an artifact of sanitizing the view to post here, but if it's in the actual SQL, then the query has a problem.

With the dummied up tables, this SQL executed without error in Oracle 12c.

Try executing the SQL as shown above from SQL*Plus and see if it works. If so, then it's the fault of the framework not parsing CTEs well (not unheard of).

Comment: Tad, thanks for this answer, but I forgot to change the name of lokd_gate in FROM clause while preparing for the question. That is not the problem. This statement is in our project which we execute at every migration, no problems with that.

Comment: Then the final statement is the correct one: "it's the fault of the framework not parsing CTEs well", and it appears that you have found the evidence of this. It's annoying, but not the first time that a tool has failed to properly accept a perfectly legal WITH clause.